# how-to-include-library-using-helper

Tags: magento2, 3rd-party-library

how to include library in magento 2 using helper as below is the class for magento 1 that is Mage::getBaseDir ,

```
 <?php

  namespace vendor\Module\Model;


   require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') '/vendor/libname/class.php');
```

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Factory Method :

```
protected $_dir;
...

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    ...        
) {
    ...
    $this->_dir = $dir;
    ...
}
```

Now, get path like this below way :

```
$this->_dir->getPath('lib'); // Output: /var/www/html/yourmagento/lib
```

You need to use this below line :

```
$this->_dir->getPath('lib')."/vendor/libname/class.php".;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer dear @Rohan Hapani,  i know this method already but my question was to solve it  using require_once

Comment: For good practise and as per magento standard way. You should use this answer.

Comment: yes you are right but i am converting task of another developer from m1 to m2, so i have to do in that way

Answer (score 0):

The answer is also available in magento 2 Vendor files
and it worked for me

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../../../lib/vendor/LibName/LibClass.php';
```